# The need for run-time memory address binding

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, cpu-architecture

I read that in modern OSes, the memory address binding is "dynamic" and occurs at run-time. But since we use virtual memory schemes, and each process gets its own virtual user memory space, why do we still late, run-time binding? Can't we do compile-time address binding, because the virtual page address will be mapped to a physical page?

Answer (score 4):

We do use link-time binding for executables on most OSes, where an executable can have itself mapped to a fixed virtual address.  It can have absolute addresses embedded all over the place without needing relocation at run-time.  And yes, this is because different processes can use the same virtual addresses.  Systems without virtual memory need each process to use different addresses.

This is not the case for libraries: Libraries can't know what range of addresses will be free in any given process that wants to load it, so it has to use [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code).

OS X also requires PIC for executables.  I've never looked up why; maybe they want to be able to do [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

I might be totally mistaken, but I think I remember reading that Win9x didn't require position-independent code, and installing a DLL involved coordinating with other installed DLLs on the system to find absolute address ranges that could be used.

Comment: (Correction, I don't think MacOS *requires* PIC executables, but it does always load them outside the low 4GiB so you can never take advantage of 32-bit absolute addresses, e.g. for `mov eax, [table + rax*4]`)

Answer (score 4):

Virtual memory and dynamic binding are two independent concepts. Dynamic binding is done in systems without virtual memory.

In most cases, applications try to use position independent code. That is code that can be loaded anywhere in memory and still execute correctly. Compilers generate position independent code using offsets. Many processors allow relative addressing from the Program Counter/Instruction Pointer register to access memory locations.

You can have a global variable like:

```
int x ;
```

and reference it

```
main ()
{ 
   int y = x + 1 ;
}
```

The compiler and linker can user relative addressing to that the program can be placed in memory anywhere.

Things like this cause problems with relative addressing at link time:

```
static int *x = &y ;
```

Your linker has two choices here. Ether it can force y to be at a fixed location (meaning the code is not position independent) or it can include an address fixup to be resolved at run time (what is normally done). In the latter case, the program loader reads the fixup from the executable file and initializes the variable to the address when it is loaded.

The other fixup that takes place is when you have shared libraries (aka DLLs). A shared library can be updated without requiring all the programs that link to it to be relinked. Shared libraries have a table of their universal symbols (i.e. those can can be seen outside the library, such as the names of library functions). If you add code to the library, things can move around.

When you link to a shared library, the executable will define a dynamic mapping to the globals in the shared library (generally functions) that it uses. At run time, the loader will use this information in the executable to find the addresses of the functions referenced and fix up the addresses to match those where it loads the shared library.